# How to create a formula (SUBTOTAL) below table

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

I use EPPLus to create a excel file with a table in it. Creating the excel file and table works like a charm using:

```
worksheet.Cells["A1"].LoadFromCollection(rows, true, TableStyles.Light12);
```

...but when I try to insert a formula into the first empty row after the table, the file becomes corrupt and cannot be opened normally. Excel can recover it though, but the formula I added will never show.

I use this line of code to create the formula:

```
worksheet.Cells["E"+(rows.Count+2).ToString()].Formula = "=SUBTOTAL(109;[TurnoverCurrent])";
```

I've already confirm that I'm targeting the correct cell, and if I insert just a string instead of a formula, it works. Hence my feeling is that I don't use the formula method correctly. How can I achieve a SUBTOTAL formula after my table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three things jump out at me, and I'm not sure if either/or will fix it, but I thought to offer.

1) your `subtotal` formula is right next to the table -- when Excel renders the XML, is it trying to add this to the table and freaking out because it's self-referencing?  In other words, the subtotal formula is now part of the table and adding itself?

2) when I use subtotal, I use a comma, not a semicolon

3) you didn't reference the table name in your formula.  Since this is a brand new sheet, it's safe to try `Table1`.  If you really want to be fancy, you can look up the table and find its name.  I wouldn't.

So maybe add one row, prefix the table name and change your semicolon to a comma?

```
worksheet.Cells[rows.Count + 3, 5].Formula = "=SUBTOTAL(109,Table1[TurnoverCurrent])";
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

`worksheet.Cells["E" + (rows.Count+2).ToString()].Formula = "=SUBTOTAL(109;[TurnoverCurrent])";`

to

`worksheet.Cells["E" + (rows.Count+2).ToString()].Formula = "SUBTOTAL(109;[TurnoverCurrent])";`

Do nut use the "="

Comment: This does not seem to make any difference, I get the exact same error when opening the file..

Comment: Try replacing the ";" in the formula with a "," EDIT : Seems Hambone already suggested that..